Why did the NAV of the Chinese index tracking ETF ASHR change during Chinese holiday?
The Chinese market is closed from 10/1/2024 to 10/7/2024 for National Holiday.  The ETF ASHR attempts to track the Chinese CSI 300 Index and holds Chinese A-shares.  Why did the NAV of the fund change significantly from $28.94 on 9/30 to $32.58 on 10/4 when the Chinese market was closed?  During the same period USD/CNH rose over 1% so it can't be due to currency exchange difference.
Taking the fund's top holding on 10/4 Kweichow Moutai Co Ltd as an example,
433,597 shares * closing price on 9/30 CNY 1748 = CNY 757927556 ~= USD 107.99M

The market value in the table $127.47M is over 18% more.


This question is similar to: How are ETF prices calculated after the market is closed. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@nanoman This question asks about the NAV, not the market price.

The NAV is made up of stocks it holds whose prices can change after hours.

(Require further research, hence a comment) Many CSI 300 Index companies are also listed on the Hong Kong Stock Exchange, which remained open between 2024-10-02 to 2024-10-04 and on 2024-10-07. The A-shares are probably not traded but the NAV calculations might derive from that of the H-shares.
